# PyQt5 QML currentIndexChanged signal

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5, qt-signals

The problem is as follows.

I have this ListView in a "main.qml" QML file:

```
ListView {
    id: websiteListView
    orientation: ListView.Vertical
    flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: websiteModel
    focus: true
    highlight: Rectangle { color: "lightsteelblue";}
    highlightFollowsCurrentItem: true
    objectName: "websiteListView"

    delegate: Component {
        Item {
            property variant itemData: model.modelData
            width: parent.width
            height: 20

            Row {
                id: row1
                spacing: 10
                anchors.fill: parent

                Text {
                    text: name
                    font.bold: true
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                }

                MouseArea {
                    id: websiteMouseArea
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        websiteListView.currentIndex = index
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also possess this Python script:

```
    self.__engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    self.__engine.load("main.qml")

    website_list = self.__engine.rootObjects()[0].findChild(QObject, "websiteListView")
    website_list.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.__website_event_print)
```

And the function responsible for signal handling:

```
@pyqtSlot(int, int)
def __website_event_print(self, current, previous):

    print(current)
    print(previous)
```

The code shown above is just an excerpt from the whole application but I believe that other lines of code will have nothing to do with the problem.

As I am trying to run my application an error occurs

```
TypeError: decorated slot has no signature compatible with currentIndexChanged()
```

I have tried already a plentiful of variations of above code but nothing seems to work. Is my style of handling the signal correct ? And if so, what is the signature of the "currentIndexChanged" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not advisable to connect qml items outside of QML since you can only obtain it as `QObject` as your code shows and never the real object since it is private, besides `currentIndexChanged` notifies that there has been a change but no parameter passes it for what you get those mistakes.

A possible solution is to create an object that is inserted in QML through `setContextProperty()` and invoke the function when the signal is emited:

**.py:**

```py
class Helper(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def foo(self, index):
        print(index)

# ...

engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
helper = Helper()
engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("helper", helper)
engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile("main.qml"))
```

.qml

```
ListView {
    onCurrentIndexChanged: helper.foo(currentIndex)
    // ...
}
```

<sub>In the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/47376517) there is an example</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much ! It does work and is much simpler than I thought ! I think you have mispelled foo in qml and wrote fun.